# Should Constructor Parameter Names be Abbreviations of Instance Variables?

Tags: oop, parameters, constructor

For example, with this class,

```
class Dog {
    String name;
    int colour;
}
```

would it better to have a constructor with parameters that have the same name as the instance variables they represent, like this:

```
    public Dog(String name, int colour) {
        this.name = name;
        this.colour = colour;
    }
```

Or is it better to abbreviate the names of the parameters, like this:

```
    public Dog(String n, int col) {
        name = n;
        colour = col;
    }
```

Comment: Whichever you like. And, if you care about other developers being able to read your code easily, you should use expressive names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s better to use the full field name for parameters, because it’s clearer.

Even though it take’s slightly more code (adding `this.`), clarity wins.

Also, it avoids the problem of naming convention when two fields share the same first letter.